# What versions of Eclipse RTC Plugin does BlueMix DevOps support?

Tags: ibm-cloud, devops

My team currently uses BlueMix Devops and would like to download the latest version of the Eclipse RTC plugin (ver 6) into my eclipse environment because it has a couple bug fixes that would really help me.

What RTC Plugin versions are supported against BlueMix DevOps?
What version of RTC is installed on BlueMix DevOps?
When can we expect version 6 of Eclipse RTC to be supported by the BlueMix DevOps?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently it is based on RTC 5.0.2 and it supports RTC Client 5.0.2
No idea about plans to upgrade.

Comment: After checking with the DevOps team, there are no currently plans to support Eclipse RTC plugin V6.